Text content gets removed when a new extension is created for it when the extension tag has textcontent and node element data together with it
Text content gets removed when an extension a new extension is created for it when the extension tag has textcontent and node element data together with it
My extension
export const Tbcaption = Node.create({
  name: "tbcaption",

  addOptions() {
    return {
      HTMLAttributes: {},
    };
  },

  group: "block",

  content: "inline*",
  addAttributes() {
    return {
      class: {
         default: "tb-caption",
      },
      id: {
        default: null,
      },
    };
  },
  parseHTML() {
    return [{ tag: "caption" }];
  },
  renderHTML({ HTMLAttributes }) {
    return ["caption", mergeAttributes(this.options.HTMLAttributes, HTMLAttributes), 0];
  },
});

Expected
This is the given node to this extension
<p class="Captiontitle" data-id="caption"><strong>Table&nbsp;1.
    Simulation Results: Number of Clusters </strong>
    <inline-formula>
        <tex-math>
            $\mathbf{\mathit{ρ}}_{2}=0.05$
        </tex-math>
    </inline-formula>
    <strong>
        and
    </strong>
    <inline-formula>
        <tex-math>
            $\mathbf{\mathit{ρ}}_{3}=0.003$
        </tex-math>
    </inline-formula>
</p>

But after getting processed by the extension we are getting this as the renderHTML for caption
<caption class="Captiontitle" data-id="caption">
    <inline-formula>
        <tex-math>
            $\mathbf{\mathit{ρ}}_{2}=0.05$
        </tex-math>
    </inline-formula>
    <strong>
        and
    </strong>
    <inline-formula>
        <tex-math>
            $\mathbf{\mathit{ρ}}_{3}=0.003$
        </tex-math>
    </inline-formula>
</caption>

Actual Behaviour
Below data in the given paragraph is getting removed
<strong>
  Table&nbsp;1. Simulation Results: Number of Clusters
</strong>

Have tried most of all the content methods mentioned in the documentaion
content: inline*

content: (inline|text)+

content: (inline|paragraph)+

content: paragraph*

content: paragraph+

and so on

Any reason for passing <p class="Captiontitle" data-id="caption"> to the node? instead of using the tag as specified in parseHTML?

That p is coming from XML Conversion to Doc format

content: 'inline*' should work well. content: paragraph also should work, but will insert an extra <p> in your html code.
How are you inserting this caption? Maybe something is wrong with this code?
Also make sure that your <strong> node is actually inline, and make sure that you are not having multiple <strong> nodes.

I have tried with content: "inline*" but it was not working.
Why can't we have multiple strong nodes?
